# Замена сессии другого пользователя

Tags: java, servlet

На [этом](http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/java/singleton_member_field_race_condition.html) сайте написано, что может быть такое, что пользователь может увидеть страницу предназначенную для другого пользователя, то есть получается, что сессия подменяется.

Можете ли вы прокомментировать? Ведь у каждого пользователя запускается сессия только для него.

Как может быть такое?

Comment: На сайте нет уведомления об ответах, только зашел на сайт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что написано по ссылке, никакого отношения к сессии не имеет. Там говориться про то, что для сервлета создается один экземпляр(т.е. используется патерн синглтон) и потом этот один экземпляр обрабатывает все запросы предназначенные для него(в несколько потоков, а не последовательно). И если хранить состояние юзера как поле в этом классе, ничего хорошего не выйдет, потому что данные будут перетираться разными юзерами.

Comment: А что не так с этим классом, переменная не статик ведь.

Comment: @JTan Так и экземпляр один, т.е. все потоки будут использовать эту переменную.

Comment: А как я могу сделать так чтобы разные сессии использовали свои переменные?

Comment: @JTan нужно использовать объект Session который можно получить из ServletRequest. Как с ним работать можно прочитать тут: http://www.fcet.staffs.ac.uk/gdm1/general/java/web/servlets/scopes.asp в секции Session attributes.

Comment: То есть значения надо будет сохранять в сессии,

Comment: @JTan Да. Всякие аннотации и красивости из того же Spring MVC, для работы с переменными сессии, не более чем сахар, в реальности оно всё так же хранится в сессии.

Comment: Это очень странно, зачем разработчики  так сделали, ведь это ничем не выгодно или есть какая то польза.

Comment: @JTan Что именно странно? По моему вполне логичное решение, что за сессию отвечает запрос, а не сам сервлет, который ОДИН на приложение.

Comment: Странно то что одна переменная к примеру String string доступна только в одном экземпляре для всех сессий, то есть хранит только одно значение для всех сессий.

Comment: правильно ли я понимаю что если будет 1000 запросов в один момент  и там будет переменная к примеру String тогда возможно что они будут использовать одинаковые значения. хотя в каждой сессии в этой переменной будет храниться в этой переменной разные значения

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30861/discussion-between-vartlok-and-j-tan).